# "Ill" word meaning in 17th century 1608

Tags: british-english, early-modern-english, seventeenth-century-english

I'm writing a script set in 1608 in British English from the 17th century. I want to know the exact meaning that the word "ill" had at that time?

1. We appear just as **ill**. (We look just as sick). Refering to sickness.
2. He has an **ill** will. (He has a wicked will). Meaning evil or deviant.

Are both meanings correct for that time?

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/ill

Comment: If you go to the full OED it will show the history of each sense of the word.